# write request to database

Tags: database, postgresql

I am working on chat app that needs to cater handling `100k` incoming message per second.
I am thinking of go with `postgresql` but not sure if it fits.

**Chat app feature** 
- individual chat or group chat
- delete chat once it is delivered and read by all user involved
- have message delivery/read status like whatsapp.
- received chat will be store locally on user device

**The flow is as follow:** 
- for every new message coming in (emitted from socket io), we need to write into Message table and Message Delivery Table 
- let say i am in a group of 50 people, i need to create each row for each member (49 rows) in Message Delivery Table as well on top of the sent message in Message Table. 
- after user received or read, we need to update back the status to Message Delivery Table as well as local database in user app
- if all user is received and read, we need to delete all the relevant message in Message table and Message Delivery Table

**Note:** 
- The data must be hosted on own premise. 
- Will not be subscribing any paid service.

Not sure I am asking the correct questions, but what is the end result is there must not be siginificant delay when handling 100k message per second in the chat app.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking at the wrong technology as your base.  Take a look at something like ActiveMQ, Kafka, or even Redis pub-sub.  This would allow you to better handle the load, accomplish the publish and receive type mechanics you want while still allowing you to pipe the data to a database if that is really necessary.

If you google for chat and any of the technologies listed above, you should find more than a couple of examples to bootstrap your knowledge.  Here is one https://www.sothawo.com/2017/07/a-simple-web-based-chat-application-built-with-kotlin-vaadin-spring-boot-and-apache-kafka/ that shows a chat app with kafka.

Ultimately, you can do this with a database only, but you will spend a lot of time AND money trying to get it to scale to 100k per second.